# WebSocket4Net synchronous calls

Tags: c#, synchronization, websocket4net

I might missing something on documentation but there is any possibility when the 'Send' method is called to wait for the answer and not through a callback method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because was used different threads I used  `ManualResetEvent`. After `send` method (from `WebSocket`) was called the thread was put on hold using `WaitOne` method from `ManualResetEvent` and on ws response the Set method was called and the response was read from a local variable.